# canvas.getImageData: "Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18"

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've read that it is not possible to use getImageData on an image loaded from a different domain. Any trick to overcome this?

Thanks

Comment: That's an important security feature, and if there were a "trick" to get around it the security of the Internet would be severely, if not completely, compromised.

Comment: @Pointy, please elaborate on that. I'm not saying you're wrong, I just want to hear the full details on why that is such a critical thing.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a proxy script on your domain that forwards the image from the other domain.

Comment: do you have an example or a url or a preferred way that you could share?

Answer (score 1):

Well,If you know something about python,Try
`python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
 in your teminal,
 change your testing html file name into  `index.html` 
and enter `local:8000` to start your test