# Pixastic with externally hosted images

Tags: canvas, webkit, pixastic

I am using the Vimeo API to get thumbnails of videos which I would like to apply effects to using Pixastic. However, in Chrome and Safari I get the error message: "Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18". I have tried drawing the external images to canvas elements and then applying the Pixastic effects to those canvas elements but I get the same error message.

Is anyone successfully using Pixastic with external images in Webkit?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3276072/canvas-getimagedata-uncaught-error-security-err-dom-exception-18 .

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too, only I didn't realize my problem was external images. Changing from absolute to root relative links worked for me.

```
didn't work: http://domain.com/image.jpg

will work:   /image.jpg
```

Pixastic can't work on external images due to a [canvas security limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5515535/48523). The way around this is to either create a proxy to serve the external images as if they were local, or you will have to copy the images.